# Converting mssql trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i just moved from mssql to mysql and what i'm doing now is converting all my triggers in mssql to mysql and i'm finding difficulites. I'm inserting a record
into a table called `pp_change` and when that is done a table called `profile` should be updated and lastly insert the record in a `photo` table

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER pic_pic AFTER INSERT ON pp_change
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN      

BEGIN             
    UPDATE profile           
    SET  profile_pix = pp_change.pic           
    FROM Inserted pp_change          
   WHERE profile.email = pp_change.email          

INSERT INTO photos (email,pic,wardrobe,upload_type,pic_view,up_user_id,country,time_group,fpage)                            

SELECT (email,pic,wardrobe,upload_type,pic_view,user_id,country,time_group,fpage) 
from pp_change             

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When i execute i get this error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Inserted pp_change
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has no concept of `inserted`.  It uses the `new` variables to store the new values.  So, you should be using them, and not the original table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER pic_pic AFTER INSERT ON pp_change
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN      

BEGIN             
    UPDATE profile           
        SET  profile_pix = new.pic           
        WHERE profile.email = new.email ;         

    INSERT INTO photos (email, pic, wardrobe, upload_type, pic_view, up_user_id, country, time_group, fpage)                            
        SELECT new.email, new.pic, new.wardrobe, new.upload_type, new.pic_view, new.user_id, new.country, new.time_group, new.fpage;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Comment: @neiza . . . Nothing obvious is jumping out as a problem with the syntax.